# htaccess redirect to a new domain only when there is a query string is present

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a rewrite so the URL will go to an different IP address only when certain query word is in the URL

when /CheckBalance is in the url the query information needs to be redirected to a different IP

example:
http://example.com/CheckBalance.aspx?CID=068530002570394286

needs to redirect to....

http://143.229.203.144/CheckBalance.aspx?CID=068530002570394286

Note: the number that is passed in for CID= could be a different number each time and they all need to be sent to the new IP.

if there is no query in URL I need it to not redirect
will still go to http://example.com

Comment: To check for a query string use "%{QUERY_STRING}". %{REQUEST_URI} does not check the query.

Comment: So, you don't need to check for a certain query word in the url. Which query word do to need to check after the question mark?

Comment: @WendiT "CID" (Without quotes) for example.

Comment: I've changed my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/CheckBalance.aspx
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^CID
RewriteRule (.*) http://143.229.203.144/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If the url after the domain starts with CheckBalance.aspx (line 1) and the query starts with CID (line 2) replace the domain with ip address 143.229.203.144

Comment: Close, but you have to add **?** at the end of the replacement URL. The query, when present, is automatically added except when there is a question mark at the end of the replacement URL (i.e. **....144/$1? [R=301,L]**. On the other hand, as the location of the key **CID** inside the query is not known, you can skip the **^** to allow to be detected at any position. Try to add flag **NC** to conditions to allow the comparison to be made [in a case-insensitive manner](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc)

Comment: Thank you!  FYI, I had to add QSA to keep the rest of the query from being cut off.  [R-301,L,QSA]